# Reading Pipe from cmd.exe that uses "start" builtin

Tags: pipe, cmd

I'm attempting to "leave a message" for the current user (on Windows) using WScript.exe, without waiting for the user to acknowledge the message.

My thought was to create a new process, using the "start" builtin (it usually opens a new window and execution control returns to the caller) and call WScript with a short script to open a message box on the screen and then exit.

This works OK unless I attempt to open a pipe from that script (and read it). If I attempt to read from the pipe, the read I/O never gets EOF until wscript.exe exits, even though that program continues execution after the "start" command.

Here's an example:

**test.vbs**

```
WScript.Echo "Hello World!"
```

**invoke.cmd**

```
start wscript.exe //nologo test.vbs
@echo Exiting...
exit /b
```

If I run invoke.cmd in a command prompt, the WScript window opens and control returns to the prompt.

However, if I attempt to pipe the output to a command (that attempts to read the pipe), the subcommand never seems to see that the pipe has closed until **wscript.exe** exits.

This behavior doesn't require WScript.exe, however. It seems to behave this way as long as the process created by "start" is still running. I can get the same behavior with "cmd.exe /k".

**invoke2.cmd**

```
start cmd /k date /t
@echo Exiting...
exit /b
```

Attempting to read from a pipe from invoke2.cmd blocks until the "start"-ed process ends.

I don't see any command-line args to "start" that claim to govern behavior like this, and I don't really understand why the cmd.exe that's using "start" to create new processes/windows won't exit until the "start"-ed window exits.

Curiously enough, things work if I redirect the output to a file. It just doesn't work with a pipe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using wscript.exe, it is popping up a message box on your Echo command. Try running

`start cscript.exe //nologo test.vbs`

cscript.exe is the command line version, so it will output to the command line.